# How to decrypt veracrypt on linux?

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, disk-encryption, decryption, veracrypt

I have a laptop with an encrypted windows partition and want to decrypt it using veracrypt on a live linux. There seems to be no option, however, to decrypt the partition with the veracrypt gui in ubuntu.

How can I do this?

Comment: It isn't clear where the problem lies.  For example, live sessions tend to use minimal configurations.  Does the live session include veracrypt?  If not, is the problem trying to add it to the live session?

Comment: i already downloaded veracrypt to the live session, the problem is that the documentation says, a partition can be decrypted by using  Volumes -> Permanently Decrypt. This option is not offered in the linux version / i cant find it

Comment: Do you want to mount it or permanently decrypt it? If it’s the latter, can you mount it?

Comment: I want to permanently decrypt it. Mounting works only in RO, since windows shut down in hibernation mode. I cant however fully shut down windows, as its partition is encrypted.

Comment: @fixer1234 Adding extra features to a booted live session is very easy. Your changes are lost on reboot, but that does not stop you customising it for that session. For example, I tend to use grub-customiser and KDE Partition Manager in my Linux Mint Cinnamon sessions even though they don't come with those tools. A simple `apt install` and I'm done.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible, they only implemented this for windows. See changelog for version 1.12 (August 5th, 2015): https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Release%20Notes.html